# set codeigniter output cache for individual users

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

$this->output->cache(MINUTES);
Is it possible for setting cache for individual users? There's a tourist spot listing page and showing it using cache. when one customer changes the location filter from  one computer, the next user results the other users list.

cache one users results on cache and showing it individually?

Answer (score 1):

No, Caching For Individual User is not applicable till now in code igniter.You can check and learn for  caching : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/caching.html